# Turning off dplyr messages when using dplyr functions in your own packages in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have written an R package that has a function that uses `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise`. How do I ensure that users who use that function aren't subjected to the `summarise() has grouped output by ‘X’. You can override using the .groups argument.` message?

I can of course turn the message off by setting `options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)` but I would think this isn't good practice as it might turn off the options globally for anyone who loads the package. Is there a way I can turn off the message only for the function calls from my package?

Comment: `options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we don't want to use `options` or `.groups`, can wrap with `suppressMessages`

```
library(dplyr)
suppressMessages(mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl, vs) %>% 
     summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)))
```